# Encountering "Boost.Python error script „unpackfs" while trying to install Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I have tried to install Lubuntu 18.10 but always with this error:

```
Boost.Python error script „unpackfs“.
Command '['mount', '/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs', '/tmp/tmpxfkwn4il/filesystem', '-t', 'squashfs', '-o', 'loop']' returned non-zero exit status 32.
None

Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/unpackfs/main.py", line 318, in run
    return unpackop.run()

  File "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/unpackfs/main.py", line 189, in run
    self.mount_image(entry, imgmountdir)

  File "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/unpackfs/main.py", line 239, in mount_image
    "-o", "loop"

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
```

Comment: 18.10 is out of support. Please try with  a supported release.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem too after using Rufus to write the ISO to USB. You might have noticed a few errors after you select "Start Lubuntu", and you probably ignored them.

**Solution:**

Use [Power ISO](https://www.poweriso.com/download.php) to write Lubuntu ISO to your USB.

- Install PowerISO (free version is fine)
- Go to Tools --> Create Bootable USB
- Select your USB and ISO and 'start'.

Comment: The dialog box which asks you to register, you can close that and proceed with the steps. I had have also used the unregistered version for that purpose. And you don't need to purchase because PowerISO with Crack is also available. Alternatively, you can use Ubuntu's startup disk maker also!